# How to unpack Option in Future?

Tags: scala

I want to implement a method which creates a user if it does not exist yet. If it does exist, the user should be returned.

Here's my code:

```
def createUserIfNotExists(user: User) = {
for {
  count <- userService.count(Some(user))
  user <- if (count == 0) createUser(user) else userService.findOneByName(user.name)
} yield user
}
```

My problem is that `findOneByName` returns `Future[Option[User]]` and `createUser` returns `Future[User]` so the types don't match.

How can I unpack `Future[Option[User]]` to `Future[User]` or throw an exception in case there is `None`?

Comment: The `for` comprehension serves no purpose.

Comment: @jwvh Why? Could you please explain?

Comment: SO comments won't allow me to present formatted code but CNTL-copy the following and insert whitespace to taste: `def createUserIfNotExists(user: User) =
  if(userService.count(Some(user)) > 0)
    userService.findOneByName(user.name)
  else createUser(user)`

Comment: @jwvh The reason I use for comprehensions is to resolve Futures.

Comment: Ah, my bad.  It wasn't clear to me that `count()` also returns a `Future`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make `createUser` also return `Future[Option[_]]`

```
def createUserIfNotExists(user: User) = {
  for {
   count <- userService.count(Some(user))
   userOpt <- if (count == 0) createUser(user).map(Some(_)) else userService.findOneByName(user.name)
  } yield userOpt
}
```

**or**

You can do `.get` on the option because if count is not zero that means user is definitely available in the database.

```
def createUserIfNotExists(user: User) = {
  for {
   count <- userService.count(Some(user))
   user <- if (count == 0) createUser(user) else userService.findOneByName(user.name).map(_.get)
  } yield user
}
```

**or**

First try to retrieve the user if not create the user

```
def createUserIfNotExists(user: User) = {
 for {
   userOpt <- userService.findOneByName(user.name)
   user <-  userOpt match {
      case Some(value) => value
      case None => createUser(user).map(_ => user)
   }
 } yield user
}
```

*Note that to ensure correctness in case of parallel database operations it is highly recommended to execute the above code in a `transaction`*

Comment: your 3rd answer won't compile. You're mixing types in a for-comprehension.

Comment: @wheaties .. edited the answer .. PLease check... I didn;t worry about types as complete code is not given in the questions satisfying compiler is left to user. I am interested in giving the main idea (crux of the solution only)

Answer (score 2):

Just `map` the `createUser` function return type:

```
if (count == 0) createUser(user).map(Option(_)) else userService.findOneByName(user.name)
```

The fact that the return type of `findOneByName` contains an `Option` suggests that you might not have a user. That type exists for a reason, so throwing it away is bad because it throws away information.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `findOneByName` function directly so you don't have to query the DB twice:

```
val res: Future[UserDB] = 
  userService
    .findOneByName(user.name)
    // if the option in the future is not empty, return its content
    // otherwise create a new user
    .flatMap(_.map(Future.successful).getOrElse(createUser(user)))
```